# How to move multidimensional array into Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have this javascript array from json and I want expected output below using javascript ?
Can someone give some direction.

```
[
    [{ "Key": 7, "Value": "Tours & experiances" }],
    [{ "Key": 6, "Value": "Theatre, dance and film" }],
    [
        { "Key": 2, "Value": "Children & family" },
        { "Key": 5, "Value": "Talks, course & workshops" }
    ],
    [{ "Key": 4, "Value": "Music" }],
    [{ "Key": 9, "Value": "Sports & fitness" }],
    [
        { "Key": 3, "Value": "Eat and drink" },
        { "Key": 8, "Value": "Shopping, markets & fairs" }
    ]
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
    { "Key": 7, "Value": "Tours & experiances" },
    { "Key": 6, "Value": "Theatre, dance and film" },
    { "Key": 2, "Value": "Children & family" },
    { "Key": 5, "Value": "Talks, course & workshops" },
    { "Key": 4, "Value": "Music" },
    { "Key": 9, "Value": "Sports & fitness" },
    { "Key": 3, "Value": "Eat and drink" },
    { "Key": 8, "Value": "Shopping, markets & fairs" } 
]
```

Comment: You can use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert an infinite number of nested arrays into one array.

```js
const data = [
  [{ "Key": 7, "Value": "Tours & experiances" }],
  [{ "Key": 6, "Value": "Theatre, dance and film" }],
  [
    { "Key": 2, "Value": "Children & family" },
    { "Key": 5, "Value": "Talks, course & workshops" }
  ],
  [{ "Key": 4, "Value": "Music" }],
  [{ "Key": 9, "Value": "Sports & fitness" }],
  [
    { "Key": 3, "Value": "Eat and drink" },
    { "Key": 8, "Value": "Shopping, markets & fairs" }
  ]
];

const result = data.flat(Infinity);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
let input = [
    [{ "Key": 7, "Value": "Tours & experiances" }],
    [{ "Key": 6, "Value": "Theatre, dance and film" }],
    [
        { "Key": 2, "Value": "Children & family" },
        { "Key": 5, "Value": "Talks, course & workshops" }
    ],
    [{ "Key": 4, "Value": "Music" }],
    [{ "Key": 9, "Value": "Sports & fitness" }],
    [
        { "Key": 3, "Value": "Eat and drink" },
        { "Key": 8, "Value": "Shopping, markets & fairs" }
    ]
];

let result = input.flatMap(x => x);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. you save my day ;)